Spring Cloud Microservice based project shows Bad Request This combination of host and port requires TLS from Gateway when enable SSL in all service
In one of my Spring Cloud (Eureka) based Microservice projects, I am trying to enable SSL. The project contains a Discovery Server, Gateway, and Two Service (service-a, and service-b). I include SSL-related configuration in all four applications. Here are those:
Discovery Server application.properties:
spring.application.name=serviceregistry
server.port=8848

eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false

eureka.instance.prefer-ip-address=false
eureka.instance.hostname=localhost
eureka.instance.lease-expiration-duration-in-seconds=30
eureka.instance.lease-renewal-interval-in-seconds=15

# SSL
server.ssl.enabled=true
server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
server.ssl.key-store=<ROOT_PATH>\\sslkey24.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password=PASSWORD
server.ssl.key-alias=ALIAS

Cloud Gateway application.yml:
server:
    port: 8849
    ssl:
        enabled: true
        key-store-type: PKCS12
        key-store: <ROOT_PATH>\\sslkey24.p12
        key-store-password: PASSWORD
        key-alias: ALIAS

spring:
    application:
        name: cloud-gateway
    cloud:
        discovery:
            enabled: true
        gateway:
            routes:
                - id: service-a
                  uri: lb://service-a
                  predicates:
                    - Path=/service-a/**

                - id: service-b
                  uri: lb://service-b
                  predicates:
                    - Path=/service-b/**
eureka:
    client:
        register-with-eureka: true
        fetch-registry: true
        service-url:
            defaultZone: <DISCOVERY_SERVER_URL>/eureka
    instance:
        hostname: localhost
        prefer-ip-address: false
        ip-address: 127.0.0.1
        lease-expiration-duration-in-seconds: 30
        lease-renewal-interval-in-seconds: 15

Service A application.properties:
spring.application.name=service-a

server.port=8611
server.servlet.context-path=/service-a
server.error.include-binding-errors: always
server.error.include-stacktrace=never


server.ssl.enabled=true
server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
server.ssl.key-store=<ROOT_PATH>\\sslkey24.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password=PASSWORD
server.ssl.key-alias=ALIAS

# Cloud Gateway
eureka.instance.hostname=localhost
eureka.instance.prefer-ip-address=false
eureka.instance.ip-address=127.0.0.1
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=<DISCOVERY_SERVER_URL>/eureka
#eureka.instance.secure-port-enabled=true
#eureka.instance.secure-port=8611
eureka.instance.lease-expiration-duration-in-seconds=30
eureka.instance.lease-renewal-interval-in-seconds=15

Service B application.properties:
spring.application.name=service-b
server.port=8612
server.servlet.context-path=/service-b

# Cloud Gateway
eureka.instance.hostname=localhost
eureka.instance.prefer-ip-address=false
eureka.instance.ip-address=127.0.0.1
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=<DISCOVERY_SERVER_URL>/eureka
eureka.instance.lease-expiration-duration-in-seconds=30
eureka.instance.lease-renewal-interval-in-seconds=15

# SSL
server.ssl.enabled=true
server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
server.ssl.key-store=<ROOT_PATH>\\sslkey24.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password=PASSWORD
server.ssl.key-alias=ALIAS

So the problem occurred when I raised a request to service-a or service-b through the gateway. I mean my gateway is running on port 8849, so when I request is raised through port 8849, I receive:
Bad Request
This combination of host and port requires TLS.
When I disable SSL from service-a and service-b and enable it only on the gateway, the SSL works fine. I have no idea why the issue occurs!
I am curious to know whether it is a best practice or not to enable SSL in the gateway and disable it in other services (when there is no inter-service communication).
I am using Spring Boot 3.3.4 and Java 21.
Can anyone help me determine the root cause of the error and possible solution?

Thanks


After doing several R&D, I discovered that no matter whether I include SSL configuration in all of my services when registered on the discovery service, they don't register as HTTPS.
So we need to include two more properties in all of our services. Those are:
eureka.instance.secure-port-enabled=true
eureka.instance.secure-port=<PORT_NUMBER>

What happened when we include these lines?
Behavior:

The eureka.instance.secure-port-enabled=true property indicates that the service is accessible over HTTPS
The eureka.instance.secure-port=<PORT_NUMBER> specifies the port where the service is listening for secure (SSL/TLS) communication.
Eureka will register the service with both a port (for HTTP, if applicable) and securePort (for HTTPS).

Eureka Metadata:
When the service registers itself with Eureka, it will include:

securePort: <PORT_NUMBER> (HTTPS)
port: Default HTTP port (if configured)
metadata.securePortEnabled: true

How the Gateway Knows:
When the Gateway resolves the service from Eureka, it inspects the metadata and looks at:

Whether secure-port-enabled is true.
Whether the downstream service URL should start with https:// and use the secure-port value.
Eureka clients (like Spring Cloud Gateway) automatically construct URLs for communication based on this metadata.

